# Pandas: reindex with dates in groupby, filling/maintaining values as appropriate

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following DataFrame.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': ['2010-05-01', '2010-07-01', '2010-06-01', '2010-10-01'], 'id': [1,1,2,2], 'val': [50,60,70,80], 'other': ['uno', 'uno', 'dos', 'dos']})
>>> df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d))
>>> df
        date  id other  val
0 2010-05-01   1   uno   50
1 2010-07-01   1   uno   60
2 2010-06-01   2   dos   70
3 2010-10-01   2   dos   80
```

I want to expand this DataFrame so that it contains rows for all months in 2010.

- The DataFrame is grouped by `id`, so we would have 12 rows for each id. In this case, total of 24 rows.
- The `val` at each month, if absent from the initial DataFrame, should be 0.
- The `other` has a 1-to-1 relationship with the `id`, so I would like to maintain it that way.

My desired result is the following:

```
         date  id other  val
0  2010-01-01   1   uno    0
1  2010-02-01   1   uno    0
2  2010-03-01   1   uno    0
3  2010-04-01   1   uno    0
4  2010-05-01   1   uno    50
5  2010-06-01   1   uno    0
6  2010-07-01   1   uno    60
7  2010-08-01   1   uno    0
8  2010-09-01   1   uno    0
9  2010-10-01   1   uno    0
10 2010-11-01   1   uno    0
11 2010-12-01   1   uno    0
12 2010-01-01   2   dos    0
13 2010-02-01   2   dos    0
14 2010-03-01   2   dos    0
15 2010-04-01   2   dos    0
16 2010-05-01   2   dos    0
17 2010-06-01   2   dos    70
18 2010-07-01   2   dos    0
19 2010-08-01   2   dos    0
20 2010-09-01   2   dos    0
21 2010-10-01   2   dos    80
22 2010-11-01   2   dos    0
23 2010-12-01   2   dos    0
```

---

What I have tried:

I have tried to groupby('id'), then apply. The applied function reindexes the group. But I haven't managed to both fill the `val` with zeroes, and maintain `other`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `groupby` by custom function with `reindex` and filling `NaN`s - in `other` by `ffill` and `bfill` (forward and back filling) and in `val` by `fillna` by constant:

```
def f(x):
    x = x.reindex(pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2010-12-01', freq='MS'))
    x['other'] = x['other'].ffill().bfill()
    x['val'] = x['val'].fillna(0)
    return (x)


df = df.set_index('date')
       .groupby('id')
       .apply(f).rename_axis(('id','date'))
       .drop('id', 1).reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df)
    id       date other   val
0    1 2010-01-01   uno   0.0
1    1 2010-02-01   uno   0.0
2    1 2010-03-01   uno   0.0
3    1 2010-04-01   uno   0.0
4    1 2010-05-01   uno  50.0
5    1 2010-06-01   uno   0.0
6    1 2010-07-01   uno  60.0
7    1 2010-08-01   uno   0.0
8    1 2010-09-01   uno   0.0
9    1 2010-10-01   uno   0.0
10   1 2010-11-01   uno   0.0
11   1 2010-12-01   uno   0.0
12   2 2010-01-01   dos   0.0
13   2 2010-02-01   dos   0.0
14   2 2010-03-01   dos   0.0
15   2 2010-04-01   dos   0.0
16   2 2010-05-01   dos   0.0
17   2 2010-06-01   dos  70.0
18   2 2010-07-01   dos   0.0
19   2 2010-08-01   dos   0.0
20   2 2010-09-01   dos   0.0
21   2 2010-10-01   dos  80.0
22   2 2010-11-01   dos   0.0
23   2 2010-12-01   dos   0.0
```

Another solution is create [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and reindex by it:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['id'].unique(),
                                  pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2010-12-01', freq='MS')], 
                                  names=('id','date'))

df = df.set_index(['id','date']).reindex(mux).reset_index()
df['val'] = df['val'].fillna(0)
df['other'] = df.groupby('id')['other'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

---

```
print (df)
    id       date other   val
0    1 2010-01-01   uno   0.0
1    1 2010-02-01   uno   0.0
2    1 2010-03-01   uno   0.0
3    1 2010-04-01   uno   0.0
4    1 2010-05-01   uno  50.0
5    1 2010-06-01   uno   0.0
6    1 2010-07-01   uno  60.0
7    1 2010-08-01   uno   0.0
8    1 2010-09-01   uno   0.0
9    1 2010-10-01   uno   0.0
10   1 2010-11-01   uno   0.0
11   1 2010-12-01   uno   0.0
12   2 2010-01-01   dos   0.0
13   2 2010-02-01   dos   0.0
14   2 2010-03-01   dos   0.0
15   2 2010-04-01   dos   0.0
16   2 2010-05-01   dos   0.0
17   2 2010-06-01   dos  70.0
18   2 2010-07-01   dos   0.0
19   2 2010-08-01   dos   0.0
20   2 2010-09-01   dos   0.0
21   2 2010-10-01   dos  80.0
22   2 2010-11-01   dos   0.0
23   2 2010-12-01   dos   0.0
```

Comment: Sorry, I had an outdated bootstrap code. I've updated it. A problem is that not all ids have values in January or December.

Comment: With the updated bootstrap code, and using this solution, I only get May-July for id1 and July-Oct for id2

Comment: Is there only year 2010?

Comment: You can assume you have a min_date = '2010-01-01' and a max_date = '2010-12-01'

Comment: pd.MultiIndex solution for me was a winner.  For me, that was most understandable and easier to customize.